How can I create and use a custom syntax highlight style for minted?
As far as I know, the information is scattered, and there isn't a straightforward tutorial that makes this easy to accomplish. The only question that specifically addressed this has been closed and has been viewed over 2,000 times.

Suppose I want to replicate the following style:

I took this code snippet from the Write your own style section and customized it based on the code snippet above, and saved it as example_style.py.
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.token import Comment, Error, Generic, Keyword, Literal, \
     Name, Number, Operator, Other, Punctuation, String, Text, Whitespace


class ExampleStyle(Style):

    styles = {
        Token:                  '',
        Comment:                '#990011',
        Keyword:                'bold #197fd5',
        Name:                   '#000',
        Name.Class:             'bold',
        Name.Function:          'bold',
        String:                 'italic #262626'
    }

At this stage, I need to make the style accessible to Pygments by registering it as a plugin.
How can I register the style as a plugin for Pygments?

Given that pygments isn't a latex specific tool, you might find more experts e.g. on SO

Depending on which changes you would like to make, a new style might not be necessary and you could instead patch an existing style. See e.g. https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=8045#a7657 for an example.

I think I'll post the various solutions as soon as I've tested them.

Finally, after blood sweat and tears I did it.
